# C# Retrieve Hardware Information on Remote PC without WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

In my companies environment WMI is not allowed and blocked by ACLs, what alternatives are there to get hardware information such as ram count for example without the use of WMI. I use mostly C# but if there is another language I can use to achieve this then I will make that work. Thanks!

Comment: without wanting to stop u from further searching i dont think its possible without WMI, the other thing to do is get the data localy and send them? so in each comp have something to capture that data u need. (pretty simple)

Comment: yea we have thought about that but that will involve more than I can explain here in our environment due to it being so locked down and many different client policies/requirements. I was starting to lose hope on a way to get around this without WMI, so as a last resort posted here hoping someone had another way. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: i feel you, we had to do the exact same thing in 3 different layers of computers with different access levels etc. but we ended up doing what I said and pipping the data from specific computers. good luck

Comment: This is a management issue, not a programming one - if you've been assigned a task to obtain this information, but the network has been actively configured to prevent you using the most obvious tools, then there's a conflict that can't be resolved via programming. Likely any workaround you devise will be similarly blocked (either already or when they spot you doing it)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that if WMI is locked, SNMP is locked too ? otherwise it should expose hardware informations on the TOP of WMI.